# login loop with python flask-login

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login

I am learning to use flask-login for a class. This is an intro class, and we are not using a db for this excercise, rather we are storing credentials (hashed) on a resing file. I am able to authenticate the user credentials, however when the user 'successfully' logs in, instead of redirecting to the protected URL, I am getting redirected to the login page.
The code:
user model:

```
class User(UserMixin):

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User{}>'.format(self)

    def __init__(self):
        self.username = None
        self.email = None
        self.password = None
        self.user_id = None

    def get_id(self):
        return self.user_id
```

login manager:

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = "login"


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user():
    return User
```

signin section:

```
user = User()
login_user(user)
return redirect(url_for('main'))
```

In all the tutorials I've been reading, there is use of a sql db. Since we are not using that, and since I don't need the logged on user to be specific at all - just to pass authentication, a lot of what I was reading wasn't workable within the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot something when defining the user loader. The function takes a `user_id` parameter and returns an object of class User, not the class itself. (See [documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works))

The following simplified example shows you a possibility of implementation without using a database.

Basically, flask-login stores the attribute id of the user object in the session cookie. Based on this id, the respective user is queried by the LoginManager within the database, which has been replaced here by the class variable / list `users`.
Database implementations usually have an id column which is defined as unique to the entry. In the example, the unique [id of the object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) is used as a substitute. This means that the mixin's getter will be overwritten. So the example keeps a list of created user objects. Within these users can be found by their id or username.

###### Flask (app.py)

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    redirect,
    render_template,
    request,
    url_for
)
from flask_login import (
    LoginManager,
    UserMixin,
    login_required,
    login_user,
    logout_user
)

class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.__class__.users.append(self)

    def get_id(self):
        return id(self)

    users = []

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, user_id):
        for usr in cls.users:
            if usr.get_id() == user_id:
                return usr
        return None

    @classmethod
    def find_by_username(cls, username):
        for usr in cls.users:
            if usr.username == username:
                return usr
        return None

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get(user_id)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    keys = ('username', 'password')
    if request.method == 'POST' and all(k in request.form for k in keys):
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        if User.find_by_username(username) is None:
            User(username, password)
            return redirect(url_for('.login'))
    return render_template('register.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        user = User.find_by_username(username)
        if user and user.password == password:
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(request.args.get('next', url_for('.index')))
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('.index'))

@app.route('/secret')
@login_required
def secret():
    return 'You found the secret.'
```

###### HTML (templates/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated -%}
    <a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a>
    {% else -%}
    <a href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Register</a> |
    <a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</a>
    {% endif -%}
    <h1>Index</h1>
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated -%}
    Welcome {{ current_user.username }}!
    {% else -%}
    Welcome Guest!
    {% endif -%}
  </body>
</html>
```

###### HTML (templates/login.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Register</a>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

###### HTML (templates/register.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Register</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed response! gonna give this a try

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I will admit I don't 100% follow all that is happening in the User class, but it looks like the big key was for the class to hold an internal representation of the attributes, rather than just authenticate statically against a resing database. If that is right, then, while it's good to know and adds security, it feels a little overcomplicated? - I would think a way where, once authenticated against db, a cookie/localStorage entry that just says 'yes' or something like that should be enough for a simple authentication pass check? Regardless, thank you very much!

Comment: I have a followup problem: with the system you wrote, once a user has logged out, they cannot log back in again. At first I got an error saying that NoneType object has no attribute 'is_active'. When I changed the user login to force='true', the attribute  error changes to 'has no attribute 'get_id''. Thoughts?

Comment: @tzvik15 I added an explanation to my answer.
Is it part of your assignment to use flask-login? You can also write authentication using a file yourself. The procedure would be to load the file and search for the credentials within the loaded users. An entry can be added to the session cookie after authentication has taken place. With the help of a decorator, it can then be verified on further page views whether this entry is available and forwarded depending on this. Leave me a comment if you need help. Maybe we can communicate in other ways.

Comment: @tzvik15 Unfortunately I cannot reproduce your error. did you change the code?

Comment: I think I solved it (for now, lol) the answer was, once authentication with the database was successful for the existance of the username/password combo, to call this line again before loging the user in: ```User(username, password)```

Comment: That doesn't seem like the solution to me. The line creates a new user and stores it in the list. The user object should actually exist, the condition ensures that beforehand.